# what is win32_NTLogEvent time generated format

Tags: wmi, event-log, win32-process

what is the meaning of eventlog time generated value in wmi "20061101185842.000000-000".

when i am using windows event viewer it gives the date and time format as " 2/13/2013 4:05:15 PM " but when i am accessing it in win32_NTLogEvent, it gives the format as "20061101185842.000000-000".

please clear my doubt...

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The WMI uses the Universal Time Coordinate (UTC) format, try these articles for more information.

- [Working with Dates and Times using WMI](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee198928.aspx)
- [Converting WMI Dates to a Standard Date-Time Format](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156576.aspx)
- [WMI Date and Time Format (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa389802%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

You can convert it to DateTime like this:

```
ManagementDateTimeConverter.ToDateTime(yourValue);
```

where yourValue is a string like this: "20061101185842.000000-000"